# Sockets sendto() returns EINVAL after previous successful call

Tags: c, sockets, udp, datagram, sendto

I've modified [this](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/talker.c) C datagram (UDP) socket client example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define SERVERPORT "4950"

volatile sig_atomic_t is_shutdown = 0;

void handler_signal(int signal)
{
    if (signal == SIGINT)
    {
        is_shutdown = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *server_info, *temp;
    int result;
    int number_bytes;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: executable [hostname]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    result = getaddrinfo(argv[1], SERVERPORT, &hints, &server_info);

    if (result != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(result));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(temp = server_info; temp != NULL; temp = temp->ai_next)
    {
        socket_fd = socket(temp->ai_family, temp->ai_socktype, temp->ai_protocol);

        if (socket_fd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(server_info);

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create socket\n");
        return 2;
    }

    //int hostname_length = strlen(argv[2]);
    unsigned long counter = 0;
    const size_t buffer_length = 50;
    char buffer[buffer_length];
    memset(&buffer, 0, buffer_length);

    while (!is_shutdown)
    {
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_length, "%lu", counter++);

        number_bytes = sendto(socket_fd, buffer, buffer_length, 0, temp->ai_addr, temp->ai_addrlen);

        if (number_bytes == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

        printf("sent %d bytes to %s.\n", number_bytes, argv[1]);
    }

    result = close(socket_fd);

    if (result == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "close error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("exiting application\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It fails on `sendto` function with `Invalid argument (errno 22)` on the second iteration of the loop. It works on the first.

However, the code works (client keeps sending messages in an infinite loop and server successfully receives them) if I change it to the following:

```
    //...

    //create a copy to pass it later
    socklen_t length = temp->ai_addrlen;
    struct sockaddr *address = temp->ai_addr;

    while (!is_shutdown)
    {
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_length, "%lu", counter++);

        number_bytes = sendto(socket_fd, buffer, buffer_length, 0, address, length);

   //...
```

What have I done here? What am I missing? I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: `if (number_bytes == -1)`:: check errno before breaking out of the loop. Could be EAGAIN , EINTR, or even resource-related for UDP.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks, I will modify it. But right now It only becomes EINVAL.

Comment: You answered your own question: `number_bytes = sendto(socket_fd, buffer, buffer_length, 0, &temp->ai_addr, temp->ai_addrlen);` :the address needs to be passed by pointer.

Comment: @wildplasser then why does it work on a first call and only fails on the second? `temp->ai_addr` is already a pointer.

Comment: `temp` is a pointer to `struct addrinfo` which value is assigned from `server_info`. But when you `freeaddrinfo(server_info);` the memory is released and `temp` points to nowhere. It works the first time because no memory reuse has happened yet. But after memory reuse it become invalid. Try to make a copy of data before to free the structure.

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed that `temp`'s fields point to the `server_info`'s fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Frankie_C pointed in his [comment]:

`temp` is a pointer to `struct addrinfo` which value is assigned from `server_info`. But when you `freeaddrinfo(server_info)` the memory is released and `temp` points to nowhere. It works the first time because no memory reuse has happened yet. But after memory reuse it become invalid. Try to make a copy of data before to free the structure.